# Daily increase on amount updates

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to increment a fee for each day after the first day for 100 days, which increases by .25.

This is my attempt, but I know I'm not doing it correctly:

```
$startday = new DateTime('2022-06-22');
$today = new DateTime();
$days  = $today->diff($startday)->format('%a');

echo $value = 100 + $days * 025;
```

Comment: Is the second day $2.25, or does that price include day 1 + day 2?

Comment: Well, to start with, today is still 6-22 (at least in parts of the world), so the difference is 0...

Comment: Next, 025 is treated as the hex value of the decimal 21

Comment: @aynber s/hex/octal/

Comment: @aynber Sammitch, would there be an easier way to implement this than what I'm currently attempting?

Comment: @Sammitch Always confuse those. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the base late fee is simply $1/day, and the $0.25/day increasing penalty.

The simple version is:

```php
function lateFee($days) {
    $base = $days;
    $penalty = 0;
    for( $i=1; $i<$days; ++$i ) {
        $penalty += 0.25 * $i;
    }
    
    return $base + $penalty;
}
```

But it can also be condensed down to:

```php
function lateFee($days) {
    return $days + array_sum(range(1, $days-1)) * 0.25;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go about this would to be to create a loop, since you're building on a previous day's fee.

```
$startday = new DateTime('2022-06-01');
$today = new DateTime();
$days = $today->diff($startday)->format('%a');

$fee = 0;
if($days) {
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $fee += 1.00 + (.25 * $i);
        $i++;
    } while($i < $days && $i <= 100);
}
echo "Fee for $days days is $fee";
```